# wordpress website display wrong in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, wordpress-theming

I have wordpress website, and the homepage of this website display incorrect in IE.
I'm developer too, so I know I have to put doctype in the header to force IE display in standard mode. But when I use developer tool in IE, it's display the doctype stay inside body tag.
Here is my website: http://kidscare.edu.vn/
and the screenshot:
http://imageshack.us/f/546/kidcareiebug.png/

The weird thing is another page is display correct. I don't understand why this error appear.

Comment: change the document mode quriks to ie7,8 anything

Comment: @Roger thanks guys, I fixed it. I just paste the code for header direct in hompage file (it's 2 file before) the the problem is solved.
So wield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this site is working perfect in all IE expect ie6 quirks mode, the prob is you are viewing this site in quirks mode,

For changing this mode `alt+7` or press `f12` than change the document mode to the standard one.

Please change this mode and this will work fine see my ss.

its how site will look in IE7+.

[image]

you can check these questions  also :

- [How do I get IE9 to use standards compliant mode when developing on
  localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049337/how-do-i-get-ie9-to-use-standards-compliant-mode-when-developing-on-localhost)
- [why am I triggering quirks mode in IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652791/why-am-i-triggering-quirks-mode-in-ie8)

Comment: I know it display in quirks mode, but the problem is when I open the homepage, the quirks mode is automatic actives, you can try other page and see the different

Answer (score 0):

You have two starting HEAD tags and one closing HEAD tag. There should be one starting and one closing HEAD tag on your page. Try removing one.

Oeps, I typed HEAD but meant HTML. There is a typo in the conditional statement at the end of the first line:

```
  <!--[if !(IE 6) | !(IE 7) | !(IE 8)  ]><!-->
    <html dir="ltr" lang="vi-VI" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#"  >
        <!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: thanks, I try to find but actually there's only 1 <head> and </head> in my source code, and this is my header.php file 
[link](http://kidscare.edu.vn/header.txt)