# How to make IE 9 Standards Mode the default mode?

Tags: internet-explorer-9, compatibility

I have a web site that works perfectly fine in IE9 when compatibility mode is turned OFF (the compatibility symbol is gray).  When compatibility mode is turned on (blue), the jQuery doesn't work at all.  I have added the following tag to the site to tell the browser that compatibility mode should NOT be used.

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" >
```

I have the doctype as this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Still, the browser doesn't seem to default to standard mode and the user must manually ensure that they are NOT in compatibility mode.

Can I disable IE 9 Compatibility Mode? Have I done what I need to do to disable IE 9 Compatibility Mode? Can the user always override IE 9 Standards Mode?

Comment: The user can always override the mode but why would they? I would only change the mode if the site looked broken and I thought I could remedy that with a mode correction (does the average user even know they have this power anyways?)

Comment: Some users come to our site and some of the jQuery does not work. They only way it doesn't work is in compatibility mode, which they have enabled. I want to force it in standards mode.

Comment: For clarification, I was addressing your last question "Can the user always override IE 9 Standards Mode?" As for the previous parts, you should be able to force the browser to use standards mode. In fact, without an example page I couldn't tell you why it isn't already. You have all the right pieces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this DOCTYPE declaration:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

As found in:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6049675/796404

Another answer was to use the new HTML5 DOCTYPE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

As stated by:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699338(v=vs.85).aspx

I hope this helps!

Comment: Your answer is part of the right answer. It seems that no matter what you do, you cannot FORCE a visitor out of compatibility mode; you can only suggest it. I hate Microsoft. :(

Comment: If the user has explicitly enabled the option, there isn't much you can do, unfortunately.  This should just prevent compatibility mode being triggered automatically.  You may be able to check for it with JavaScript and alert the user to disable the 'feature'. ;)