# No response in IE9 using jQuery on()

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, jquery-2.0

I have the following jQuery (version 2.0.3) set up to toggle my nav dropdown on both touch devices and desktops:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("Ready handler triggered");
    $(document).on({ click : ToggleNav, touchstart : ToggleNav }, "#NavToggle");
});
```

My `ToggleNav()` function:

```
ToggleNav = function(event) {
    console.log(event.type);
    $('ul#Navigation').slideToggle(200);
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

And the relevant HTML:

```
<div id='NavToggle'>Navigation</div>
<ul id='Navigation'>
    <li><a href='/' title='Home'>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href='/page-1.php' title='Page 1'>Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href='/page-2.php' title='Page 2'>Page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href='/page-3.php' title='Page 3'>Page 3</a></li>
    <li><a href='/page-4.php' title='Page 4'>Page 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

This works on every browser I've tested so far (Mac, Windows, and Chrome for Android) *except* for **IE9**, both 32 and 64-bit versions.

The funny thing is that if I open Developer Tools and refresh the page it will start working, and I can then close Developer Tools and it will continue working no matter how many times I refresh.  That is, until I close and reopen the browser.

The `event.type` is successfully logged to the console ("LOG: click"), but the slideToggle() is apparently not being triggered and no errors are being logged to the console.

Has anyone come across this before, and knows the cause and/or a solution?

**Update 1**:  I updated the `ToggleNav()` function to also alert the `event.type` since opening the console to view the log also made IE9 start working.  IE9 will not even show the alert, so the ToggleNav() function isn't even being triggered to begin with.

**Update 2**:  After a bit more testing, I think the problem lies with the original on() handler.  When I changed the `console.log("Ready handler triggered");` line to be an `alert()` instead it started working in IE9.

Comment: Could you be running IE in non-standards mode? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13199810/how-to-make-ie-9-standards-mode-the-default-mode

Comment: @JasonSperske I was already using `<!DOCTYPE html>`, and adding `header('X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge,chrome=1');` had no effect.

Comment: @jrrdnx - What's wrong with the code I posted??  I updated the answer with a working jsfiddle?

Comment: @SolomonClosson It was late and I went to bed.  The jsfiddle solution did not work for me either.  After further testing, the error might be with IE9 and jQuery's ready() handler.  I've updated my original question to show the ready() handler and an explanation in **Update 2**.

Comment: @jrrdnx - The jsfiddle I created worked perfectly fine for me in IE9.  I tested this myself with an actual IE 9 browser!

Comment: @SolomonClosson Your jsfiddle itself worked, yes.  But it did not solve the issue I was experiencing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up at my answer with some further testing and frustration.  Apparently in IE "the console object is only activated when the Dev Toolbar is opened. Prior to that, calling the console object will result in it being reported as undefined. After the toolbar has been opened, the console will exist (even if the toolbar is subsequently closed), so your console calls will then work."

See:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/7742862/866273

So both the `console.log()` in my ToggleNav function (original question) and in the ready() handler (update 2) were causing the issue, and that's why it started working when I switched `console.log()` to `alert()` (update 1).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have to invoke the function within the `.on` event handler.  Furthermore you don't need a delegated `.on` event handler for this to work, and you don't need to use `event.preventDefault();` here, so I removed it:

```
function ToggleNav() {
    $('ul#Navigation').slideToggle(200);
}
$("#NavToggle").on({ 
    click : function() { 
        $("ul#Navigation").slideToggle(200); 
    }, touchstart : ToggleNav });
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4dD9/2/)

Also, be sure that the `touchstart` event is working properly as well.  If not do the same as the `click` event is doing in the code.

Comment: Yes, I realize that.  I just remember reading that it didn't support earlier versions of IE, and thought it was ie9 and less.  Still would recommend testing with jQuery 1.x to be sure.

Comment: Placing event.preventDefault() before the slideToggle() did not work.

Comment: Can you provide the relevant HTML?

Comment: Added to original question

Comment: Updated answer, and provided jsFiddle.  Works like a charm now and if you use jQuery 1.x latest version will work in IE 8, 7, and possibly 6 as well, but that's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes IE8 and IE9 behave unexpectedly with the `$` of jQuery. Using `jQuery` in the [noconflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) has solved this issue for me.

Comment: This had no effect for me.

Comment: @jrrdnx - try using [`Click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) instead of the current [`on(click)`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: No change when using click()